# Ryu Controller gets no links

Tags: sdn, mininet, ryu

I am trying to build a ryu application with starts and tries to get the owl topology. Therefor I’m using the get_link and get_switch function from the ryu.topology.api. Getting the switches is no problem but the list of links is always empty.

I tried using the get_all_link as well but the result is the same.
So far I found a lot of examples were they use those functions but none of these work with my set up.

Here are some examples i tried:
https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/BasicTopoLearner.py

[get_all_link(self) outputting all possible LINKs for a topo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302571/get-all-linkself-outputting-all-possible-links-for-a-topo)

My Ryu version is 4.32 and Im using the tree topology from mininet

Cheers and thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable the processing of lldp packets by the controller using the `--observe-links` option when starting ryu.
Do

```
ryu-manager --observe-links your_ryu_app.py
```

Also if you try to get the links at the time mininet is building the topology you may get nothing. So try to put a timer to delay the get_all_links method, or try polling the switches using a monitor thread (see traffic monitor in Ryubook)

Comment: I wasted so many hours, trying to figure out what could be the problem just to reach here and find my stupidity!

Comment: I wasted two days trying to figure out this problem. Thank you